# emacs org-mode: completing a multi-line task

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am new to org-mode (using it under evil) and been using it as a very nice ASCII-based TODO  with scheduled times and completion dates. I have a simple question - and in my case, I think an image is worth 1000 words...

Look at the image below, in the line that starts with "Merge button: ...." - i.e the one that I've split to two lines - with the continuation line starting with "click after..."

After hitting TAB to open the action tree node, the continuation line is colored in grey - as if it's not a part of the task in question:

[image: Split lines]

This is further verified if I mark the task as DONE (shift-rightCursor): The DONE marker is placed below my task line, not below my continuation line - as if the continuation line is on its own:

[image: Wrong place to say DONE]

I am probably missing something obvious - any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: The notes underneath a heading are just regular text without any special highlighting, and that is by design.  If you place your cursor on the gray text and hit `C-u C-x =` does it show any special font at that location?  If not, then the default is nothing.  If it shows something, I'd be surprised -- so please let us know.  If it's just the default font for regular text, then you'd need to change your default font for that particular major mode, which is a slightly different question than I think you're asking.

Comment: The notes underneath a heading are very useful, and can be used also for a list / item format:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html  I use the notes to synchronize my tasks with Toodledo and have access to my todo on all mobile and desktop devices.

Comment: @lawlist: The C-u C-x warns me about a 'disabled upcase-region command' (maybe because I am using evil?). Anyway, from your other comment I take it that it's not possible to split a heading line as I did - because if you do, it's no longer part of the heading (hence the different color).

Is it possible to have the TODO/DONE 'attributes' on multi-line sections?

Comment: The easiest way I can think of to explain it is to show you.  If you type from your `org-mode` buffer (like in your example):  `M-x describe-variable RET org-complex-heading-regexp RET` you'll get a printout for the regexp used for headings based on the keywords you've defined for `org-mode`.  `org-mode` uses that regexp for many functions, and that regexp essentially defines where a heading begins and where it ends.  The only regexp I've ever seen for notes, is something that I wrote myself.  Try `M-x re-builder RET` and paste the code of the complex variable to see it in action.

Comment: The default setting for `C-u C-x =` is `(what-cursor-position t)`.  The same result can be achieved by typing `M-x eval-expression RET (what-cursor-position t) RET`

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Looking at the regexp, it is indeed clear it can't span a line (.* will not cross a line). I guess I'll just have to live with using smaller heading text, and explain it in a note underneath. You can add this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text at issue in the question of the original poster is what I generally refer to as the *notes* section of a task.  By design, `org-mode` does not assign a particular highlighting of the *notes* section -- i.e., the `default` font for text will be used.

However, all is not lost.  It is possible to change the `default` font for a particular buffer using the `face-remapping-alist` and setting it as a local variable.  The following example uses a `cyan` foreground color, but it can be just about anything:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html  I'm not certain when `setq-local` was introduced, but it is available in a current version of Emacs Trunk and may be available in earlier versions of Emacs.

---

```lisp
(defun my-org-notes-face-function ()
(interactive)
  (setq-local face-remapping-alist '(
    (default (:foreground "cyan")))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-notes-face-function)
```

Answer (score 2):

In a word, it's the Design.

You could think like this:
The headline (first line) is the title of a task, the rest are contents/description or sub tasks.